# get nested json object using postman form Web API

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, postman

I'm using Postman to retrive data form a web API that returnes a liste of Sessions, and for each Session there is an Evenement Object.

Here is the Code for the web API:

```
  [HttpGet()]
    public IActionResult GetSessions()
    {
        var sessions = _sessionBusinessService.GetAllsSessions();
        return Ok(sessions);
    }
```

Whene i debuge my code i find that GetSessions() returns all Sessions with an Evenement for each Session. But Postman shows me an error.

And when i tested that in Chrom, it retuns a non complete list:

```
 [{"sessionId":1,"evenement":{"id":2,"titre":"Présentation Asp.net Core","pitch":"pitch1","typeEvent":null,"sessions":[]}}]
```

Session Entity:

```
 public class Session
  {
    public int SessionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateDebut { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateFin { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Evenement Evenement { get; set; }

    }
```

Evenement Entity:

```
public class Evenement
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }


    public string Titre { get; set; }


    public string Pitch { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Session> Sessions { get; set; }

     }
```

Comment: What is error on postman ? have you used any session id or header in your request where it is working .

Comment: It sad "Coud not get any response".  With chrom it returns just one element and it stop just aftre the object of Evenement.